# Vite & Typescript: Yarn workspace commands running out of memory

Tags: typescript, vite, yarn-workspaces

I've set up yarn workspaces according to their documentation and added a couple packages. I'm now running into what looks like some kind of memory leak when building and running tests. I'm using Typescript and Vite for builds and Jest for testing. I have two packages: `pkg1` and `pkg2` and `pkg1` uses `pkg2` as a dependency. It is a very simple setup but I'm getting the error `FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` when running a build or test command such as `yarn workspace pkg1 build` or `yarn workspace pkg1 test`.

Here's a simplified overview of my project structure:

```yaml
packages
  - pkg1
    - src
      - components
    index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    tsconfig.node.json
    vite.config.ts
  - pkg2
    - src
      - components
    index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    tsconfig.node.json
    vite.config.ts
tsconfig.json
```

My root-level `tsconfig.json` looks like this

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "paths": {
      "@org/pkg2": ["./packages/pkg2"],
      "@org/pkg2/*": ["./packages/pkg2/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["**/cypress", "**/node_modules", "**/dist"]
}
```

And each individual package `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*", "index.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

With a `tsconfig.node.json` taken from the Vite default:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

In `pkg1`, I'm using `pkg2` as a dependency in `package.json` and importing it with:

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from "@org/pkg2";
```

To get around the memory issue, I can run the following command which works:

```bash
NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=8192" yarn workspace pkg1 build
```

But there is obviously something wrong with my set up; I shouldn't need to increase the memory to 8 gigs just to get a build to complete. I've done lots of digging around and spent 2 days trying to fix things so I'm reaching out here. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If anyone else stumbles upon this, it appears to be a known issue with Rollup. It's listed in their docs along with a similar fix to what I was already doing: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-javascript-heap-out-of-memory and there's an issue in Vite's repo: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2433. My workaround for now has been to add a `.env` file at root with `NODE_OPTIONS` setting and use it alongside `env-cmd` in package commands such as: `env-cmd -f ../../.env tsc && vite build`.